# Laravel automatic resolution with parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, ioc-container

I have a class like this:

```
class PostValidator 
{
     public function __construct(Validator $validator, $data) 
     {
          $this->validator = $validator;
          $this->data = $data;
     }
}
```

I read Laravel doc about IoC automatic resolution, it gives an example:

```
class FooBar {

    public function __construct(Baz $baz)
    {
        $this->baz = $baz;
    }

}

$fooBar = App::make('FooBar');
```

Is it possible to use `App::make` only without `App::bind` (with closure) to instantiate my class above which also passing parameter `$data`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

The idea is that you pass only the dependencies to the constructor, and obviously `data` is not one. Validator works with the data, but does not depend on the data.

Instead use setter for the data.

```
class PostValidator 
{
     public function __construct(Validator $validator)
     {
          $this->validator = $validator;
     }

     public function setData($data)
     {
          $this->data = $data;
     }
}
```

and simply call it explicitly:

```
$validator = App::make('PostValidator');
$validator->setData($data);

// or in the controller, which is what you're doing most likely
public function __construct(PostValidator $validator)
{
  $this->validaotr = $validator;
}

public function update($id)
{
  $data = Input::only([ input that you need ]);

  $this->validator->setData($data);

  // run the validation
  ...
}
```

---

edit: as per comment, this is what 2nd argument `$parameters` does:

```
// Foo class with Eloquent Models as dependencies
public function __construct(User $user, Category $category, Post $post)
{
 $this->user = $user;
 $this->category = $category;
 $this->post = $post;
}
```

then IoC container will resolve the dependencies as newly instantiated models:

```
$foo = App::make('Foo');
$foo->user; // exists = false
$foo->category; // exists = false
$foo->post; // exists = false
```

but you can do this if you want:

```
$user = User::first();
$cat = Category::find($someId);

$foo = App::make('Foo', ['category' => $cat, 'user' => $user]);
$foo->user; // exists = true, instance you provided
$foo->category; // exists = true, instance you provided
$foo->post; // exists = false, newly instantiated like before
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe another thing, `App::make` allows us to pass second argument, what is it used for?

Comment: It is used for providing concrete instances if you want - check the edit.